# Handling error from gets_s() gracefully?

Tags: c, error-handling

My code uses [gets_s()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5x9wc7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get a string input from the user.If the user enters a string whose length is greater than the specified in gets_s, the application aborts.So how to handle that gracefully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can invoke _set_invalid_parameter_handler at the beginning of your program to set a callback function to handle the error, in the callback function, you should check the value of errno.

Comment: Pinpoint answer, thanks,but the mechanism you described is only applicable in debug mode so what about release mode as that's what will be used after I finish debugging.

Comment: OK I checked, it also works in release mode, only the extra info. is not provided to the handler function.thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1) `gets_s` is not a Standard function: apparently it is provided as an extra by Microsoft compilers

2) use `fgets`, remove the trailing `'\n'` if needed and if there is no trailing `'\n'` deal with extra long input

Example

```
size_t len;
char buf[1000];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    buflen = strlen(buf);
    if (len) {
        if (buf[len - 1] == '\n') {
            buf[--len] = '\0'; /* adjust len and remove trailing newline */
        } else {
            /* something bad hapenned */
            if (len == sizeof buf - 1) {
                /* possibly large input */
            } else {
                /* small input */
            }
        }
    } else {
        /* no characters read at all, this is a strange occurrance */
    }
} else {
    /* fgets returned NULL: EOF on stdin? or maybe some error? */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help pmg but the _s versions are provided for added security so isn't it better to use them?What's your view?

Comment: Well ... crashing kinda defeats the "security" thing, doesn't it? Anyway, I think the "safe" extensions only provide false safety: many checks still have to be done by the programmer and the ones that are done by the "safe" functions aren't the most important

Comment: @rsjethani gets_s is now standard in C11. As it provides a buffer length just as fgets does, it is neither more nor less secure or crash-prone, nor does it provide any more of a false sense of safety.

Comment: From [the Draft of the C 2011 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (K.3.5.4.1/6): "... Consider using **fgets** (along with any needed processing based on new-line characters) instead of **gets_s**."